# Getting IMCE to accept multiple file uploads at one time

Tags: 7, files

I am currently using the [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce) module for uploading files but it only allows 1 file to be uploaded at one time.  We have tried the [plupload](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) and the [imce_plupload](https://drupal.org/project/imce_plupload) modules together but those modules sometimes corrupt the files once uploaded.
The only other module called "IMCE Multiple Upload" that claims that it can work with IMCE as an add-on module to IMCE and allows multiple uploads at one time costs $36.
I don't know if the "IMCE Multiple Upload" module will work correctly since the demo site only allows 5 files at once and once over a certain file size it scales it down.

Has anyone used the "IMCE Multiple Upload" module with IMCE and does it restrict how many files can be uploaded at once and does it restrict the file size?
Also does anyone know of an alternative way of getting IMCE to accept multiple file uploads at one time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Drupal you are using, If you are working with Drupal 7 you should take a look at: [IMCE plupload](https://drupal.org/project/imce_plupload) that helps you to use [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce) with [Plupload](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) .

But in Drupal 7 the best option is [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module.